# Failed to execute method-- error:Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'getCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to call a func in cell method but before that I need to call the func in View controller cell. Every time I try to call Xcode doesn't recognize it and an error appears. If I just copy it (Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'getCell').

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell1 = tableViewFullP1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell01", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

    configureCell(cell, at: indexPath) // The one I want to call in the end

    return cell
}

//Fetch Method P1
func fetchInfoToHomepage() {
    let fetchRequest88: NSFetchRequest<Information> = Information.fetchRequest()
    let sortOnDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date_info9", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest88.sortDescriptors = [sortOnDate]

    controllerItch = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest88, managedObjectContext: context77, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    controllerItch.delegate = self

    do {
        try controllerItch.performFetch()
    } catch {print("Failed fetch p1")}
}

// Sepcical func
func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var malekHosny = controllerItch.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.getCell(infos: malekHosny) //Here's the problem
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your UITableViewCell subclass *does* have a `getCell` method. So you need to cast to that subclass:

```
(cell as! TableViewCell1).getCell...
```

Comment: Or change the parameter type from UITableViewCell to TableViewCell1 in the `configureCell` method.

Comment: oh man! you're a totally genius ^_^ both ways solved the problem. although that my app still crashing